# Regex search and replace except for specific word

Tags: regex

I'm trying to search and replace some strings in my code with RegEx as follows:

replacing self.word with self.indices['word']

So for example, replace:

```
self.example
```

with

```
self.indices['example']
```

But it should work for all words, not just 'example'.
So the RegEx needed for this probably doesn't need the actual word in it.
It should actually just replace everything but the word itself.

What I tried is the following:

```
self.(.*?)
```

It works for searching all the strings that match 'self.' but when I want to change it I lose the word like 'example' so I can't change it to self.indices['example'].

Comment: Do you need this? https://regex101.com/r/yUoYon/1

Comment: @wnull Ah yes that's exactly what I meant, it works beautifully on the RegEx tester website, but when I try it on Pycharm it replaces self.example with self.indices['1']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is a substitution using capturing groups.  Depending on the language used some of the syntax might be slightly different but in general you would want something like this:

`self\.([^\s]+)`

replace with:

`self.indices['\1']`

https://regex101.com/r/R3xFZB/1

We are using the parans to caputre what is after `self.` and in the replace putting that captured data into `\1` which is the first (and in this case) only captured group.  For some languages you might need `$1` or `\\1` for the substitution variable.

As with most regexes this can be done many different ways using look arounds, etc. but I think for somebody new this is easy to read, understand and maintain.  The comment @wnull made has a more proper regex leveraging a look behind that should also do the trick :)

Comment: Yes that also works well. Also, using $1 instead of \1 seems to do the trick in PyCharm.

Comment: It seems theres just one problem left, it seems to also match what comes after the word. For example: when changing type(self.example) it becomes type(self.indices['example)'] instead of type(self.indices['example'])

Comment: To solve this I tried using self\.([^\s]+)*? but it doens't quite work either, it then becomes type(self.indices['']clients)

Comment: I managed to solve it by replacing the + with (?:(?!((| |\.|)|\,)).)* so it matches everything up to but not including one of these special characters: (),. So the final search statement becomes: self\.([^\s](?:(?!(\(| |\.|\)|\,)).)*)       Now it works perfectly.